# javascript forloop doesn't run all code

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

So I do have this loop, but it stops when it come to function after effect , also when I remove that code from loop and define x by me, it does work correctly. What is stopping that function after effect? Also when I've tryed without fadeTo and removed that function that is after effect and just putted it behind comma (`$('#item' + x + ' p').html(obchody[window.obchod][x]['doby_a_kontakty']`) it worked too (but with some error and stopped after first loop).

```
for (var x in obchody[window.obchod]) {
    $('#item' + x + ' p').fadeTo(350, 0, function () {
        $('#item' + x + ' p').html(obchody[window.obchod][x]['doby_a_kontakty']).fadeTo(350, 1);
    });
}
```

The problem continues, now when I use `this` instead of `$('#item' + x + ' p')`, it runs but late. Here is an example, I added to code something like counter - nuber(number inside function).

```
y = '';
for (var x in obchody[window.obchod]) {
    y += ' ' + x + '(';
    $('#item' + x + ' p').fadeTo(350, 0, function () {
        y += x + ')';
        $(this).html(obchody[window.obchod][x]['doby_a_kontakty'] + y).fadeTo(350, 1);
    });
}
```

And the result of this test is: y==`0( 1( 2( 3( 4( 5( 6( 7(7)7)7)7)7)7)7)7)` and I need it run like y==`0(0) 1(1) 2(2) 3(3) 4(4) 5(5) 6(6) 7(7)`, because I can't use x in that but this wouldn't help there.

Comment: Firstly, you don't need `$('#item' + x + ' p')` inside the callback function - just use `$(this)`.  Secondly, can you put it in a fiddle so we can play with it?  Also, `html(obchody[window.obchod][x]['doby_a_kontakty'])` should be changed to `html(x['doby_a_kontakty'])`.

Comment: I don't get that think with fiddle, but changing `$('#item' + x + ' p')` to `$(this)` worked, so thanks :) but no, `html(x['doby_a_kontakty'])` doesn't work, it does have to be `obchody[window.obchod][x]['doby_a_kontakty']`

Comment: So please add your solution as separate answer and accept it :-)

Comment: Don't add "solved" to the title that's not how things work here. Instead explain what you have done, if it's different than the accepted answer that was posted after your edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
function fade(x) {
    $('#item' + x + ' p').fadeTo(350, 0, function() {
        $(this).html(obchody[window.obchod][x]['doby_a_kontakty']).fadeTo(350, 1);
    });
}

for (var x in obchody[window.obchod]) {
    fade(x);
}
```

Comment: With the explanation (for the OP) being that (a) when possible you should use `this` rather than selecting the same element again via its id, but more importantly (b) by the time the callback runs the loop has finished executing so `x` will be whatever it was at the end of the loop not what it was for that particular element.

Comment: As you said, it runs like y==`0( 1( 2( 3( 4( 5( 6( 7(7)7)7)7)7)7)7)7)` but, I need it run like y==`0(0) 1(1) 2(2) 3(3) 4(4) 5(5) 6(6) 7(7)`

Comment: If you want it to do 1 fade, then callback, then the next fade etc. then you'll need to explain what obchody and obchod are.  The above amendment will not do that.

Comment: Well I solved it by 0( 1( 2( 3( 4( 5( 6( 7(7)6)5)4)3)2)1)0) (just same counter running, but y--; > `for(var x in obchody[window.obchod]){var y=x;$('#item'+x+' p').fadeTo(350,0, function(){$(this).html(obchody[window.obchod][x-y]['doby_a_kontakty']).fadeTo(350,1);y--;});}` (formating doesn't work here so..)